# Can someone send popup message to all mobile network users?

Tags: mobile

Can you detect all users in the same network cellular or mobile network as you?

Is it possible to send SMS or broadcast popup message from your mobile phone to other mobile users in your proximity?

Comment: You can create you're own GSM atennae/network and if they connect you have the ability to do whatever you feel like, with a ["HackRF"](https://greatscottgadgets.com/hackrf/) but not on public networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

#### No

From a mobile phone on AT&T, Verizon, O2, etc., to other mobile phones on the same network, no. That would be a bad idea.

#### Yes

Network operators have the ability to send certain kinds of alerts to all mobile users in an area. These alerts are Amber alerts (US) and emergency (flash flood, gas leak, etc.).

Comment: Thanks again, if the mobile providers have the ability to do it, is it theoretically technically feasible to do it from your private mobile or in any other way?

Comment: @Avi Not really, no. That functionality is intentionally limited to network operators.

Comment: So there is no way to bypass it to the your network users that are nearby you?

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: To send message to nearby mobile that are close to me in specific radius

Comment: If there was a known way, it'd be fixed pretty quickly. So no, there's no known way to bypass those controls that I am aware of.